# How to set the elements of an array according to a certain rule

Tags: javascript, arrays

Imagine we have array like this:

```js
const words = ['luigi', 'Bar', 'Test', 'zac1', 'Alf0'];
```

Now I would like to sort this array alphabetically:

```js
words.sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b));
```

Imagine we have array of super words. This words have high priority and should be on the top of 'words list'.

```js
const superWords = ["zac1", "Test"]
```

So the desired result of words array will be:

```js
const desiredResult = ["Test", "zac1","Alf0", "Bar", "luigi"]
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Why `Test` is before `zac1`  in your expected result? It should be `["zac1", "Test","Alf0", "Bar", "luigi"]` according to `superWords`, right?

Comment: I guess superWords should be also sort

Comment: @NickVu It's not ascii comparison I believe. localeCompare just takes in the alphabetical order

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could convert `superWords` into a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) for `O(1)` lookup time using [`has`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/has) rather than `O(n)` using [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) when `superWords` is an [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) (where `n` is the number of words in `superWords`):

```js
const words = ['luigi', 'Bar', 'Test', 'zac1', 'Alf0'];
const superWords = ['zac1', 'Test'];
const superWordsSet = new Set(superWords); // This is O(n) but you only need to do this once.
words.sort((a, b) => {
    if (superWordsSet.has(a) && !superWordsSet.has(b)) {
        return -1;
    } else if (!superWordsSet.has(a) && superWordsSet.has(b)) {
        return 1;
    }
    return a.localeCompare(b);
});
console.log(words);
```

> ### [**Performance**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set#performance)
>
> The `Set` [`has`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/has) method checks if a value is in a `Set` object, using an approach that is, on average, quicker than testing most of the elements that have previously been added to the `Set` object. In particular, it is, on average, faster than the [`Array.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) method when an `Array` object has a `length` equal to a `Set` object's `size`.

Comment: Awesome man! Could u explain What's going on here:
words.sort((a, b) => {
    if (superWordsSet.has(a) && !superWordsSet.has(b)) {
        return -1;
    } else if (!superWordsSet.has(a) && superWordsSet.has(b)) {
        return 1;
    }
    return a.localeCompare(b);
});

Comment: `has` returns `true` if the word is part of the set i.e., is a `superWord`. There are four possibilities, only `a` is a `superWord`, only `b` is a `superWord`, or both of them are or are not `superWord`s. Returning a negative number means that `a` should come before `b` and positive number means `b` should come before `a`.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this

```js
const words = ['luigi', 'Bar', 'Test', 'zac1', 'Alf0'];


words.sort((a, b) => {
 const superWords = ["zac1", "Test"]
 if(superWords.includes(a) && !superWords.includes(b)){
  return -1
 }else if(superWords.includes(b) && !superWords.includes(a)){
  return 1
 }
 return a.localeCompare(b)

})

console.log(words)
```

Comment: Your solution is good! Just have a small feedback, you can move `superWords` out of `sort`. That will be more effective

Comment: @NickVu you are right but since is a small array and it's scope is limited to the sorting function I think that it's cleaner this way

Answer (score 1):

First step find doubles and the your can sort both arrays and afterwards you can concat the arrays.

```js
let words = ['luigi', 'Bar', 'Test', 'zac1', 'Alf0'];
const superWords = ["zac1", "Test"]

words = words.filter(w => ! superWords.includes(w));

words.sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b));
superWords.sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b));



console.log(superWords.concat(words));
```

Answer (score 0):

This could help. You can click on 'Run code snippet' to see output:

```js
const superWords = ['zac1', 'Test'];

const words = ['luigi', 'Bar', 'Test', 'zac1', 'Alf0'];

const desiredResult = superWords.sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b));

desiredResult.push(
  ...words
  .filter((word) => !superWords.includes(word))
  .sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b))
);

console.log(desiredResult);
```

Comment: You added superWords to words and now we have duplicates. I would like to move superWords located in words to the beginning of the list - not to create new one

Comment: @INeedYourHelp sorry about that, forgot to add a condition. Fixed it